# multi-level domain ssl protection

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I am working on multi-tenant application and have domains like-

a.mydomain.com
b.a.mydomain.com

I bought a wildcard certificate with CN- *.mydomain.com and it working for a.mydomain.com but not working for b.a.mydomain.com. After some research i came to a conclusion that i will have to buy another certificate i.e *.*.mydomain.com.

my problem is how do i import second certificate into my existing java keystore and is it correct to have to certificate for one server.

any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can install multiple certificates on the same server if you have multiple IP addresses for the server. If you have only one you can do it too, as long you server and client support SNI (Server Name Indication). All modern browser do it, but IE8 and lower does not and non-browser applications often don't either.

Second, there is no technical limitation to have both `*.mydomain.com` and `*.b.mydomain.com` in a single certificate and the browsers also support it and it is also actively used. Talk to your CA (where you get the certificate from) if they will issue certificates like this, but maybe they will charge more.

Comment: SNI solution is perfect for hosting multiple domains with SSL on single IP address, but most admins are not friendly with this system. If you enable SNI on server, you can install multiple ssl on single IP address. (SNI is outcome of IPV4 shortage).

Comment: In case you can’t enable SNI on server, alternate is multi-domain ssl with wildcard domains support. In this type multi-domain ssl with wildcard, you can add multiple wildcard domain names in single ssl certificate like *.domain.com, *.a.domain.com, *.b.a.domain.com, *.anotherdomainc.com, etc.

Also you can add more domains on demand in this type ssl.

Comment: @JayDan The fact that most admins are not familiar with SNI are the least of the problem with SNI (if that's their job, they might as well learn what it's about, it shouldn't be harder than anything else). As Steffen said, the real barrier is the lack of support in applications that users may use.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install two SSL on a single server on a single IP. With the Wildcard Certificate you will only able to secure *.domain.com. Wildcard SSL is an ideal solution for protecting unlimited sub domains by getting a SSL for primary domain. For example, *.mysite.com secures www.mysite.com, register.mysite.com, etc. So, it is better to go for multi domain certificate (SAN) which allows you to secure multiple domains on a single server.

Comment: SAN would allow protection for only 100 domain but our application can create instance on demand,so i don't this SAN is fit for our need.can you suggest another way to do this?